# Does this look cryptographically sound?

Tags: python-2.7, cryptography

I'm making an encryption/decryption device in python 2.7. The ultimate goal is to allow for encrypted communication between 2 nodes using this encryption. I really just want to know if it looks like it won't easily be decrypted. I'm using system.random for this one, so the randomness of the numbers generated should be pretty good. But is the actual algorithm not too simple?

It generates a lot of random integers between 0 and 255, this is the keystream. Each character is then expressed as an integer between 0 and 255. The first character in the message is added to the first integer, the second to the second, etc. This should render the encrypted message as random as the keystream integers. I just thought I'd explain how it works instead of just posting the script.

```
def createkey():
    file = raw_input('file name to save key under:')
    maxcount = input("digits? Default is 2500.")
    if maxcount == '':
        maxcount = 2500

    digit = 0
    while digit < maxcount:
        rng=random.SystemRandom()
        key=rng.randint(100,356)
        print key
        with open(file, "a+") as myfile:
            myfile.write(str(key))
        digit = digit + 1
    myfile.close()


def encrypt():
    file_to_encrypt = raw_input('file name or path to encrypt:')

    destruct = raw_input('self destruct?')

    with open(file_to_encrypt, 'a+') as file:
        if destruct == 'y':
            file.write('\nThis message will self destruct.')

    with open(file_to_encrypt) as file:
        length = file.read()
        length = len(length)
        print length

    file_to_write = raw_input('Desired filename for encrypted info:')

    keyfile=raw_input('Key file:')

    num_chars = len(keyfile)

    count = 1
    paswd = raw_input('Enter password with which to encrypt file.')
    passum = 0
    charcount = 0
    counter = 0

    for letter in paswd:
        paschar = ord(letter)
        passum = passum + paschar
        charcount = charcount + 1
    if passum != 0:
        passum = int(math.sqrt((2 * passum) / charcount))
    else:
        pass

    with open(file_to_encrypt, 'r') as file:
        with open(keyfile) as key:
            while counter != length:
                txt = file.read(1)
                charnum = ord(txt)

                lines = key.read(3)
                x = lines
                x = int(x)
                x = x - 100
                keynum = (x)

                keynum = keynum + passum
                enmes = int(charnum) + (keynum)

                if enmes >= 256:
                    enmes = enmes - 256

                enmes = chr(enmes)
                print enmes

                enfile = open(file_to_write, 'a+')
                enfile.write(enmes)
                count = count + 1
                if count == num_chars:
                    count = 1
                counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: In general, if you have to ask if a crypto algorithm you made up yourself is easy to break, then the answer is: yes, it almost certainly is. Look up "Schneier's Law".

Comment: Here is it: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): *Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.* That applies to the whole security scheme you might come up with unless your name is "[Moxie](https://moxie.org)" or "[Whitfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitfield_Diffie)" or "Bruce", etc.

Comment: Well thanks for that brilliant insight. Why, then, do you think I'm asking it here? I think it would be pretty difficult to break a string of random characters without knowing the keystream, but I guess you have it down to a science, then.
I suppose you could decrypt this then? ù±;§ô(Â
TfÆ|]µ»

Comment: Please don't close this question; I want to give a shot at cryptanalyzing that and writing an answer on the weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have devised a Stream Cipher.  There are already tested and secure Stream Cyphers available, see [eSTREAM](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/) for some examples.

The security of a Stream Cipher depends on the security of your keystream generation.  Unless you are a crypto expert, then your keystream generator is almost certainly insecure.  You appear to be using the standard system RNG.  Such RNGs are *not* secure.  At the very least use the secure RNG your system provides.

You might want to have a look at RC4, which is now obsolescent, but is a nice simple example of a Stream Cipher.  It will stop your kid brother reading your files, unless he works for the NSA.

Comment: Stream cipher is not a perfectly defined term, but I wouldn't call that a stream cipher, because the key has to be at least three times as long as the plaintext. The key stream is usually deterministically generated from a short key. I think datenwolf is correct in saying that this is an "overcomplicated OTP".

Comment: A Stream Cipher is an OTP-lite with a deterministically generated keystream.  A true OTP has a purely random keystream.  In both cases the keystream is as long as the plaintext.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was under the impression that the SystemRandom for a RNG was pretty good for this sort of use, though?

Comment: `SystemRandom` (if implemented) is probably secure, depending on the security of the underlying operating system secure RNG.  Note that the documentation for `SecureRandom` says that the sequence is not reproducible so you will need to keep the whole keystream if you want to decrypt.  That is why a Stream Cipher with a short key is easier to work with than an OTP with a key as long as the message.